# Elastic Search prefix , suffix , EdgeGram

Tags: java, elasticsearch

how one can search a word through its middle or last English alphabets letter. for example CORPORATION is a words and I am able to search CORPORATION with its initials like COR, CO, C etc by using EdgeGram and prefix filter. but I am not able to search it with last letters or middle letters of CORPORATION that is POR or RATI or ION. is elastic search support this features? if yes then how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. Can you clarify? A code sample of your prior attempts would help understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [nGram tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/ngram-tokenizer.html) will do what you want.  It's like the Edge-nGram tokenizer, except it moves through the whole word rather than being anchored to one edge.

```
$ curl localhost:9200/test/_analyze?tokenizer=ngram&pretty' -d 'corporation' | grep token

"tokens" : [ {
"token" : "c",
"token" : "o",
"token" : "r",
"token" : "p",
"token" : "o",
"token" : "r",
"token" : "a",
"token" : "t",
"token" : "i",
"token" : "o",
"token" : "n",
"token" : "co",
"token" : "or",
"token" : "rp",
"token" : "po",
"token" : "or",
"token" : "ra",
"token" : "at",
"token" : "ti",
"token" : "io",
"token" : "on",
```